# I am trying to dial secret code like *#*#0808#*#* on keypad dialer from adb shell

Tags: android, adb

I want to dial a number through the android dialer which opens the keypad/dialer and dials the number using adb commands.

I tried to dial the number using this adb shell commands:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*#*#0808#*#*`

But that dials the number OTA as an MMI code, and that is not what we want.

I am told that the code *#*#0808#*#* is a secret code that launches a hidden menu, and that it must be dialled through the dialler.

I found out that the command:

`adb shell monkey -p com.android.dialer -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`

launches the phone app (but not the num keypad).

So, then I tried to dial it using the commands:

`adb shell monkey -p com.android.dialer/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 *#*#0808#*#*`

but that didn't work.

Could someone help why it isn't working? and How could I launch the dialer and dial that number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to reach? These code are called USSD codes (try google Android USSD codes). And they are different on every device. Ok, some of them are working on most of the phones, but it's not rule. Please be very careful with these codes since some of them can do factory reset or set-up your device improperly.

When executing these codes via adb, you need to url encode them (check https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php), so `*` is `%2A` and `#` is `%23` In your case:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:%2A%23%2A%230808%23%2A%23%2A
```

But if the code doesn't work for you when inserted via dialer, this will not work neither.
I try your code on my Sony Xperia Z5 with Android 6.0 and it didn't work :-(

BTW usb setting can be accessed via Settings>Developer Options>USB Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the commands I needed to give from the command prompt using adb shell to accomplish what I wanted.

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME

adb shell input tap 197 2523 #enter the dialer 

adb shell input tap 1272 2467 #enter the dialer keypad

adb shell input text "*#*#4412#*#*"
```

These type of numbers are called USSD codes/MMI commands.